# What does while javascript while(i&lt;9) mean?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

On [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/) site about javascript shorthands, by Sam Deering, a long-hand example is as follows (the site uses a before-and-after format):

```
var i=0;
while (i&lt;9)
{
  //do stuff
  i++; //say
}
```

While I don't understand this, I do understand the short-hand version, which is:

```
var i=9;
while(i--)
{
    //goes until i=0
}
```

I don't know about if `i` is the same in both loops, but assume that they both loop 9 times.
Because I would like to expand my limits and improve my programming skills, what does the `while (i&lt;9)` mean, and how can I use it (with other numbers)?

Comment: That's most likely an encoding issue. `&lt;` is the HTML entity for the `<` character. The author even mentions `while (i++<10)` as an alternative, so that's clearly what was intended.

Comment: Write your code without shorthands like this. It's work for minifiers.

Comment: You are receiving downvotes because most people think you are doing it very wrong. Unless you use HTML you can ignore them, `&lt;` is a proper way to escape `<` in XHTML. Using `<` might throw a draconian parse error.

Comment: I did not know I was reading a poorly written example. That was why I was asking, I am not asking about my own style, rather about a website's style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, e.g. XHTML, you must escape `<` properly as `&lt;`.

In HTML it's not necessary to do so inside `script` elements because their contents are parsed in a special way, but XML does not do these nasty things.

For example, you can write `index.xhtml`:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Some document</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
while (i &lt; 9) i++;
console.log(i); // 9
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Most people don't want to XML-escape JavaScript operators in inline scripts, so they use CDATA sections:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Some document</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
var i=0;
while (i < 9) i++;
console.log(i); // 9
]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML file most probably has some encoding quirks. `&lt;` corresponds to the less than symbol `<` in HTML entities. So really you can read that as `while (i<9)`.

Comment: Just fyi a "cymbal" is a brass thing that drummers hit with sticks; you're looking for "symbol". :)

Comment: @Pointy You know what? I actually play drums so I come across "cymbals" more than "symbols" lol. Thanks for the heads up.